# Не получается передать переменную между двумя классами Java

Tags: java, android, android-button

Работаю в Android Studio. Необходимо по нажатию кнопки передавать id из 1 класса во второй и переходить на экран 2 класса.
У меня переменная из класса 1 не передаётся в класс 2, не понимаю почему.
Пробовала также создавать отдельный класс для хранения переменных, но ничего не выходит.

1 класс:

```
private int id;
public int getId(){
     return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
     this.id = id;
}

 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
     setId(1);
     Intent i;
     i = new Intent(this, Сlass2.class);
     startActivity(i);
 }
```

2 класс:

```
    @Override
     public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        id = class1.getId(); //id = 0, а должен быть равен 1
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так передать данные не позволяет android sdk. Он подразумевает передачу данных через Intent. Примерно так:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Сlass2.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("STRING_KEY", 1);
i.putExtras(b);
startActivity(i);
```

Вытаскивать данные надо аналогично:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle b = i.getExtras();
int value = b.getInt("STRING_KEY", 0);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, всё получилось